# Changing text truncation behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, textblock

I want to display a path in a TextBlock.

Standard truncation ends up removing the relevant parts of information I want to show, since it truncates the rightmost part of the line first.

Is there any way to specify, in XAML, that the text should be truncated from the left first rather than the right?  Setting FlowDirection and TextReadingOrder doesn't seem to have any effect on the direction of truncation, as seen below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" FontSize="18" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" TextReadingOrder="UseFlowDirection" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
```

Is it possible in pure XAML, or does the solution need to be more complex than that (examining the size of the textblock on page resize and modifying the text to compensate)?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to trim the text from left when the text is too long? If so, there is no such property which can be set to help this work in UWP, you will need to trim it by yourself.

Here is my demo:

```
<TextBlock Text="Left-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-Right"
           Margin="0,5" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
           Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBlock;
    //desired width of TextBlock
    var desiredWidth = tb.DesiredSize.Width;
    //cal. char. in string
    var count = tb.Text.Count();
    var reducedText = tb.Text;
    if (reducedText != "")
    {
        //actual width of text
        var textWidth = tb.ActualWidth;
        //trim count
        var trimCount = Math.Ceiling((count / textWidth) * desiredWidth) - 4;
        reducedText = "... " + reducedText.Substring((int)(count - trimCount), (int)trimCount);
        tb.Text = reducedText;
    }
}
```

My demo only consider the scenario which the text is very long (ActualWidth > DesiredWidth), you will also implement the scenario if the size is enough to hold the text. And be careful that this method only works in `Loaded` event since `ActualWidth` will be changed to its rendered width instead of the text-width then the `TextBlock` is rendered completely.

Also, since you're using data binding for the `Text` property of `TextBlock`, you may create a `converter` to trim the text.